# Android ListView with custom view - get elements

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I create a list view with this tutorial - http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Now I have a questions:
1. How to create a button like "Check All"/"Uncheck All" ?
2. How to have access to some view element (like edittext) in a single row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your answer is in the tutorial as well...

Check the tutorial link again. There is a private `class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<country>{}` which is your answer.

When you bind your data to `listview` using adapter (in this case `MyCustomAdapter` is your adapter), for each element of your data array the `@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { }` method will fire.

`View convertView` parameter in the `@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { }` method is a view for each single row of your listview. If you have define xml template for your listview row with id for each element in a row, you can find element using...

```
TextView code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
CheckBox name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

Here code and name are TextBox & CheckBox of the view from specific row.

So run through the example tutorial again and I think you probably would get your answer.

Comment: Yeap - done :)

public void onBtnWyczysc(View v)
 {
  ArrayList<Wskaznik> listaWskaznikow = dataAdapter.listaWskaznikow;
  for (int i=0; i<listaWskaznikow.size(); i++) {
   Wskaznik parametr = listaWskaznikow.get(i);
   parametr.setZaznaczony(false);
  }
  dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }